# New Stack Exchange for Microsoft Office

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm a new user here and regularly check Super User. I find many questions related to Microsoft Excel so I was thinking maybe we can have a separate SE site for Microsoft Office products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suggest a new site on [Area51](http:////area51.stackexchange.com).

I see some problems with your proposal though:

- Currently there are already quite some sites where questions regarding Microsoft Office applications are on-topic: Stack Overflow for programming related questions, Super User for usage question, Web Apps for the online Office apps.
- Also, given that reason, we don't want to have multiple sites covering the same subject. You will often have duplicate questions cross-site, which won't help the overall quality.
- Given that first reason, there might only be a small part that isn't covered on either of those sites. I doubt if that subject is large enough to make it an entire site.

Comment: Thanks! I see we already have 'Ask Microsoft' proposed there. That'll do.